# Run content script when URL Subdirectories Change for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension that will parse parts of a Google Mail email for the sender's email address and validate it based on an email API. The extension is up and running however, the `content.js` script will only work when I refresh the page after opening an email. I have my `manifest.json` set to match on `https://mail.google.com/*` and I want it to run every time the subdirectory changes.

Basically, I want to be able to run the content script every time the URL changes from `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FMfcgzGpFWLJXXbptnzzBMFCmMqFVTsz`

to

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/FMfcgzGmvpHMHxJwNhRgHdFNMHTDKnNq`

How would I enable my `content.js` to detect whenever the URLs subdirectory is changed?

Also would it be better to change my `manifest.json` set to match `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/*` instead of `https://mail.google.com/*`

```
content.js

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    /* Logic to parse email */
}
```

```
manifest.json

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*"],
    "js":      ["jQuery.js", "content.js"]
}],

"permissions": ["tabs", "https://*/"]
```

Comment: Add a listener for `hashchange` event in your content script.

Comment: Do you have an article or example you could point to? Or would I just change `window.addEventListener('load', function () {parsing code}` to `window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {parsing}`